# Override registration form in FOSUserBundle Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, cdn

I am trying to override the default areas of the fosuserbundle registration form. I added all the required fields I wanted through database and customize with the bootstrap cdn. But when I try to customize the defaults fields of the registration form, I cannot find it in both **register_content.html.twig** and **register.html.twig** to edit them.

**register_content.html.twig**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>

        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**register.html.twig**

```
{% extends "@FOSUser/layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "@FOSUser/Registration/register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

I would like to customize all the following textareas.

- Email
- Username
- Password
- Repeat password

Where can I find the above fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override existing FormType then follow that doc: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

If you want to choose specific fields in html, you can select fields like that:

`{{ form_widget(form.email) }}`

`{{ form_widget(form.username) }}`

or

`{{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}`

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: of course, do you want to override registration form model ? or only separate the inputs in html ?

Comment: I guess I want to separate the inputs so that I can customize it.

Comment: then use like that for each field: `<div>{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</div>` also you can use like that: `{{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can find its at `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php` if you want to change its directy

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}
```

But it better to override the forme type as below in config.yml (create a new formType)

```
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```